# Problem with the fgetcsv() in php

Tags: php

I have the following piece of code to parse a csv file. After that I am displaying it. The .csv  file is displaying perfectly on my local  machine but on the server after clicking on upload a blank page is displaying.

```
function uploadTrainees()
{
    $csv = array();
    $tmpName = $_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'];
    //echo $tmpName;
    //ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings',true);
    $fp = fopen($tmpName,'r');
    $fields = array('delegate_title', 'delegate_firstname', 'delegate_lastname', 'delegate_jobtitle', 'delegate_email', 'delegate_phone', 'is_bringing_own_laptop');
    $records = array();

    while ($record = fgetcsv($fp,1000,','))
    {
        $records[] = array_combine($fields, $record);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Help me to solve this issue.

Comment: I am getting an error log Call to undefined function:  array_combine()  also

Comment: Do you know the PHP version of your server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of PHP is the live server running?

The function [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) is only in PHP5

**Edit**

There is a function here to do this - http://snipplr.com/view/4918/arraycombine-for-php4/

```
if (!function_exists('array_combine'))
{
    function array_combine($arr1,$arr2) {
       $out = array();
       foreach ($arr1 as $key1 => $value1) {
        $out[$value1] = $arr2[$key1];
       }
       return $out;
    }
}
```

Comment: any substitute method for array_combine() in versio 4 nmethod is there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,The problem is on server not in the local machine now the page gets reloaded after clicking on upload but csv file data has not displayed .and in logs "apache in free(): warning: junk pointer, too high to make sense" is displaying.